# How to update payload info for python scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a python scraper that works for this site:

https://dhhr.wv.gov/COVID-19/Pages/default.aspx

It will scrape the tooltips from one of the graphs that is navigated to by clicking the "Positive Case Trends" link in the above URL.

here is my code:

```
import re
import requests
import json
from datetime import date
url4 = 'https://wabi-us-gov-virginia-api.analysis.usgovcloudapi.net/public/reports/querydata?synchronous=true'
# payload:
x=r'{"version":"1.0.0","queries":[{"Query":{"Commands":[{"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand":{"Query":{"Version":2,"From":[{"Name":"c","Entity":"Case Data"}],"Select":[{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"c"}},"Property":"Lab Report Date"},"Name":"Case Data.Lab Add Date"},{"Aggregation":{"Expression":{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"c"}},"Property":"Daily Confirmed Cases"}},"Function":0},"Name":"Sum(Case Data.Daily Confirmed Cases)"},{"Aggregation":{"Expression":{"Column":{"Expression":{"SourceRef":{"Source":"c"}},"Property":"Daily Probable Cases"}},"Function":0},"Name":"Sum(Case Data.Daily Probable Cases)"}]},"Binding":{"Primary":{"Groupings":[{"Projections":[0,1,2]}]},"DataReduction":{"DataVolume":4,"Primary":{"BinnedLineSample":{}}},"Version":1}}}]},"CacheKey":"{\"Commands\":[{\"SemanticQueryDataShapeCommand\":{\"Query\":{\"Version\":2,\"From\":[{\"Name\":\"c\",\"Entity\":\"Case Data\"}],\"Select\":[{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"c\"}},\"Property\":\"Lab Report Date\"},\"Name\":\"Case Data.Lab Add Date\"},{\"Aggregation\":{\"Expression\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"c\"}},\"Property\":\"Daily Confirmed Cases\"}},\"Function\":0},\"Name\":\"Sum(Case Data.Daily Confirmed Cases)\"},{\"Aggregation\":{\"Expression\":{\"Column\":{\"Expression\":{\"SourceRef\":{\"Source\":\"c\"}},\"Property\":\"Daily Probable Cases\"}},\"Function\":0},\"Name\":\"Sum(Case Data.Daily Probable Cases)\"}]},\"Binding\":{\"Primary\":{\"Groupings\":[{\"Projections\":[0,1,2]}]},\"DataReduction\":{\"DataVolume\":4,\"Primary\":{\"BinnedLineSample\":{}}},\"Version\":1}}}]}","QueryId":"","ApplicationContext":{"DatasetId":"fb9b182d-de95-4d65-9aba-3e505de8eb75","Sources":[{"ReportId":"dbabbc9f-cc0d-4dd0-827f-5d25eeca98f6"}]}}],"cancelQueries":[],"modelId":339580}'
x=x.replace("\\\'","'")
json_data = json.loads(x)
final_data2 = requests.post(url4, json=json_data, headers={'X-PowerBI-ResourceKey': 'ab4e5874-7bbf-44c9-9443-0701abdee612'}).json()
print(json.dumps(final_data2))
```

The issue is that some days it stops working because the payload and X-PowerBI-ResourceKey header parameter values change and i have to find and manually copy and paste the new values from browser inspection network section into my source. Is there a way to programatically obtain these from the webpage and construct them in my code?

Comment: I don't think people are going to check inside the page to let you know how to get that information, and it looks like you already know how to do it. Why don't you use another script (or part of this) to look for it first?

Comment: I am not following your suggestion and not sure what you mean by look for it first? Can you elaborate. I am stuck at how to construct the payload and obtain the header parameter in my script rather than hard coding it the way I am doing now.

Comment: How is this related to Scrapy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the resource key is part of the iframe url encoded as base64.

```py
from base64 import b64decode
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests


resp = requests.get('https://dhhr.wv.gov/COVID-19/Pages/default.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)

data = soup.find_all('iframe')[0]['src'].split('=').pop()
decoded = json.loads(b64decode(data).decode())
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for taking the time and thanks for not brushing me off!